# Multiple IP for 1 Azure Deployment

Tags: azure

Is there a way to get multiple IP addresses for one Azure deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You get a single IP address per deployment. You can have up to 25 endpoints (ports) that are exposed externally, but just one IP address.